# Max NDVI per month & year using Google Earth Engine to CSV - CSV gives -999 values only

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, ndvi, time-series, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

This question refers to [Calculating NDVI per region, month & year with Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348887)

I have modified the code posted by @Kel Markert at https://code.earthengine.google.com/349615d7802d59f677181bef0badad9f to attempt to get a maximum monthly NDVI value from a small polygon over a number of years from Landsat 8 in Google Earth Engine and export to CSV.

The output .csv table only gives -999 values for all months when using the max reducer `reducer: ee.Reducer.max()`. When using the median reducer `reducer: ee.Reducer.median()`, the output provides meaningful values.

Is Max the incorrect reducer to use?

[Code Link to Google Earth Engine Script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d6521dcfcdaba6347661ebeff75e13a6)

[Table asset link - region polygon](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/mangrovewatch/MCM1)

```
    var region = table,
L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA");

var cloudlessNDVI = L8.map(function(image) {
  // Get a cloud score in [0, 100].
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');

  // Create a mask of cloudy pixels from an arbitrary threshold.
  var mask = cloud.lte(20);

  // Compute NDVI.
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');

  // Return the masked image with an NDVI band.
  return image.addBands(ndvi).updateMask(mask);
});

var startDate = ee.Date('2013-05-01'); // set analysis start time
var endDate = ee.Date('2019-12-31'); // set analysis end time

// calculate the number of months to process
var nMonths = ee.Number(endDate.difference(startDate,'month')).round();

// get a list of time strings to pass into a dictionary later on
var monList = ee.List.sequence(0, nMonths).map(function (n) {
  return startDate.advance(n, 'month').format('YYYMMdd');
})
print(monList)

var result = region.map(function(feature){
  // map over each month
  var timeSeries = ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n){
    // calculate the offset from startDate
    var ini = startDate.advance(n,'month');
    // advance just one month
    var end = ini.advance(1,'month');
    // filter and reduce
    var data = cloudlessNDVI.filterDate(ini,end).max().reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 30
    });
    // get the value and check that it has data
    var val = ee.Number(data.get('NDVI'));
    val = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(val,val,-999));
    // return max
    return val;
  });
  // create new dictionary with date strings and values
  var timeDict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(monList,timeSeries);
  // return feature with a timeseries property and results
  return feature.set(timeDict);
});

// print to see if it is doing what we expect...
print(result);

// Export the data to a table for further analysis
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:result,
  description:"MCM1_NDVI",
  fileFormat:"CSV",
  //selectors:["HRpcode","timeseries"]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the answer you want with the small geometry you use using a different approach. Note that a Landsat pixel and the scale you are currently using is 30m. Your geometry is just about 10x10m.

Add the moment you are using an unweighted reducer (`ee.Reducer.max`), which will only take pixels into account if the centroid is within the geometry ([see here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region)). Neither the geometry nor the scale you are using apparently include the centroid of the pixels, thus you return no valid values (which you set to -999 afterwards).

You have two options:

**1)** Use a scale which will include the centroid and use the unweighted reducer. Set the scale for example at 10m or calculate approximately the scale of a square geometry using:

```
var scale = table.geometry().area(1).sqrt();
```

**2)** Use a weighted reducer which will include pixels which approximately include at least [0.5% of the pixel](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region). An example would be using a mean reducer. In such a small region you probably aggregate one pixel, so that is fine for your max outcome.

```
var data = cloudlessNDVI.filterDate(ini,end).max().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: feature.geometry(),
  scale: 30
});
```

[Here an example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a735f68cf7076136882351ef21a590f0) returning both values (and you will see they are similar, confirming there is just one pixel in the region).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks @Kuik. Very clearly answered. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your region is too small. I've tried running this code with a full county in Hawaii, and it worked fine:

```
var region = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Kalawao'));
```

Additionally, I created a polygon on the map centered on your `table` object but about 3x the size, and the code ran fine with -999 results occurring only rarely:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[149.18765874159647,-21.07471411401736],
   [149.1883158828051,-21.07471411401736],
   [149.1883158828051,-21.074181016177615],
   [149.18765874159647,-21.074181016177615],
   [149.18765874159647,-21.07471411401736]]);

var region = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);
```

Substituting either of these regions for your original table work as expected.

Comment: Many thanks @JepsonNomad. Weird that it works with Median but not Max? I would've though that 100m2 would be suitable for Landsat eg. contain enough pixels?

Comment: A landsat pixel should be about 900m2 if it's 30m on a side - so if you're just sampling one pixel at each timepoint, maybe EarthEngine will give you the median (which is just that pixel's value) but doesn't like the idea of calling max? That's just a guess though...